# What's the opposite of "in X's favor"?

Tags: antonyms, expression-choice, legalese

If you argued your case well, the judge may rule **"in your favor"**.

What's the opposite expression?

(I don't mean "dismiss your claim" or "reject your suit" etc. - I'm looking for the exact opposite expression; and I'm guessing it's not "in your disfavor"...)

Note this isn't really a legal expression even though it's used often (always?) in a legal context; so I'm not looking for a legal term or expression.

Comment: He rules against you, or he rules in favor of your opponent.

Comment: @Hellion: "Rules against you" - more the rhetorical opposite of "rules for you". As for ruling in favor of my opponent - while that's a logical equivalent, it's not a rhetorical one...

Comment: Since "rules for you" and "rules in your favor" are in fact equivalent, "rules against you" can be the opposite of both.... I feel as if you're getting into the territory of "I need the opposite of *bright*, but it can't be *dark*, because that's the opposite of *light*."

Comment: @Hellion: I want a more flowery figure of speech. You can tell me that none exists, and that's a valid answer.

Comment: A more flowery wording that might actually be used in some legal settings: "The judge rules adversely to your interests."

Answer (score 2):

The judge may ***[rule against you](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rule+against)*** (or your motion):

> to give a judgment against someone or something

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: "rule against you" is more like the opposite of "rule for you" (like "find for you" and "find against you"). I want that, you know, literary shade of the 'favor'.

Comment: @empokium http://www.wordreference.com/fren/donner%20raison%20à%20qqn;  http://www.wordreference.com/fren/donner%20tort%20à

Comment: @Elian: The French is very interesting in this case. What's the opposite in French of "donner raison a" ?

Comment: @einpoklum "donner tort à"

Comment: @Elian A-ha! Maybe what I'm looking for is an expression using "tort", which is a word used in English, after all.

Comment: @einpoklum http://www.wordreference.com/fren/donner%20tort%20à ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I feel as if I can say "against one's favour", but the symmetry isn't there (in vs. out, for vs. against).

Perhaps because we have an idiomatic phrase to start, the opposite must itself be idiomatic.

Comment: "against the favor" is not the opposite of "in the favor". IMHO.